# Objective-C: NSMutableArray initialized and added to properly, but values cannot be retrieved

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

so I have a subclass of UIScrollingView that's got an NSMutableArray off all it's views. I populate this array by passing in the series of views I want to add to it. However, when I go to retrieve these views in my touchesEnded function, I get a crash. Here is the offending code

```
#import "StageScrollView.h"
#import "Stage.h"


@implementation StageScrollView

@synthesize controller;

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{

    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil)
    {
        stages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if(stages == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@".......");
    }

    int index = (int)[controller getCurrentStage];
    Stage *currentStage = [stages objectAtIndex:index];



    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint spawn = [touch locationInView:currentStage];

    Performer *temp = [[Performer alloc] init];
    [temp setFrame:CGRectMake(spawn.x, spawn.y, 25, 25)];

    [currentStage addPerformer:temp];

    NSLog(@"Touch ended!! %i", index);

}

//we probably shouldn't init stages here...best practices????
-(void)addStage:(Stage *)stageToAdd
{

    //[stageToAdd retain];

    [stages addObject:[stageToAdd retain]];
    [self addSubview:stageToAdd];

    Stage *temp = [stages objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);
}


@end
```

note that I've initialized the NSMutableArray in `initWithCoder`, as I'm loading from a nib. And yes, when I print the 0th element in the `addStage` function, it does print properly. But when I try to retrieve the 0th element in the `touchesEnded` function, no dice. For what it's worth, when I try to inspect stages in the debugger, it tries to read it as an `NSCFString`. The view controller `controller` is set via IB.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not the answer you want, but `[stages addObject:[stageToAdd retain]]` is incorrect. The array will already retain objects added to it. All you're doing here is leaking `stageToAdd`. You should be using `[stages addObject:stageToAdd]`

Comment: yeah, the retain was part of one of my attempted solutions. will remove now, thanks!

Comment: what kind of crash you get? hm... are you sure that getCurrentStage method not removes object from array?

Comment: Not sure if it's the mistake, but you should use [super initWithCoder] instead of [super init] inside your initWithCoder method

Comment: What kind of crash you retrieved? Did you check your index value? Probably index > stages.count

Comment: Also try `NSLog`ing index and `[stages count]` in `touchesEnded`.

Comment: I think Lolloz89 is right. I woul use init. And Kevin is right too. The "retian" is not requried but it does not harm for the moment. In the end it may cause a leak. So get rid of it. To your question: What exactly does getCurrentStage return? If it returns 5 in the event that it is the 5th stage, then you may address a non-existing object in the array in the following line of code. However, if debugging shows that the object is a string then try to enable zombies. Your array may be released somewhere and re-used by a string object. But listen to Lolloz89. It was probably never allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is loading from a Nib you could try:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    stages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

If this is a subclass of UIViewController there is also the option:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    stages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [stages release];
    stages = nil;
}
```